# "Желательно" в середине предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

> В предложении желательно наличие не более десяти слов.

На gramota.ru видел, что постановка слова *желательно*, как в первом примере, не является правильной, и что правильно будет так:

> Желательно, чтобы в предложении было не более десяти слов.

Так ли это?

Comment: А можно ссылку на тот вопрос?

Comment: @oleedd Поискал по истории браузера, но, к сожалению, найти не могу. Могу что-то путать.

Comment: Вот список всех вопросов с "желательно": http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=желательно Всего 18 страниц. Найти легко, если ещё какое-то слово оттуда помните. Просто это важно.

Comment: @oleedd Спасибо. Посмотрю сегодня попозже.

Comment: @oleedd ‟В предложении должно быть не более десяти слов” – а с этим предложением всё в порядке?

Comment: @JimKorbett Это звучит нормально. Нашёл ещё одну проблему. "Наличие" используется, когда говорится о чём-то конкретном, и оно не используется просто для указания количества. Например, нельзя сказать: *В этом предложении наличие восьми слов.* И даже так нельзя: *Мне нужно наличие восьми слов.* Но можно так: *Мне нужно наличие местоимения.* Говорится о конкретном.

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить первоначальный вид предложения можно: достаточно внести в него подразумеваемое сказуемое **иметь**. В таком случае слово *желательно*, которое в исходной фразе выглядит неубедительно: то ли оно предикативное наречие, то ли краткое прилагательное, выступит наречием («*Желательно знать точно, так ли это*»). Такой частью речи, надо думать, и gramota.ru в этой фразе его определила.

**В предложении желательно иметь наличие не более десяти слов.**

> В этих условиях особое значение будет иметь наличие в составе нового
> ЗРК пассивной инфракрасной станции обнаружения воздушных целей.
>
> Не надо забывать, что в этот период мы будем иметь наличие норм
> „буржуазного права», которое именно в этот период придется
> преодолевать.

Вариант gramota.ru не плох, но правит фразу слишком решительно. Можно так:

*В предложении желательно ограничиться наличием десяти слов.*

Comment: А "наличие" и "иметь" не совпадают по смыслу? *Желательно иметь паспорт. Желательно наличие паспорта.* Но не: *Желательно иметь наличие паспорта.* Наличие подразумевает имение. Плеоназм какой-то.

Comment: Необходим глагол, и в этом смысл реконструкции. (*иметь в наличии имущество, необходимо иметь в наличии все сущности, не помешает иметь в наличии силы безопасности*) Если видите тавтологию, покажите её.

Comment: Далеко не всегда такое уместно. В заданном примере звучит избыточно.

Comment: Не в этом проблема вопроса.

Comment: Стоп. А вы хитры. Вы же заменили на "в наличие", и поэтому звучит. Так и в ответе замените.

Comment: "Быть в наличии" похоже на легальный плеоназм (устойчивое). Словарное значение "в наличии": ***Есть**, **имеется**, налицо.*

Comment: Исправил бы на легальный, но два предлога **в** фразу не украсит.

Comment: Даже и не заметил. Между ними дистанция. Явно лучше звучит, плавнее.

Comment: "Наличие" не для указания ограничения, оно для указания присутствия. А вы глаголом "ограничиться" ещё больше подчеркнули ограничение. Плоховато звучит. Лучше без "наличие": *Желательно ограничиться десятью словами.*

Answer (score 1):

Смотрим толковый словарь на Грамота.ру:

**ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНЫЙ**, соответствующий чьим-л. желаниям, интересам; нужный, необходимый. Ж. результат. Ж-ое решение. Дорога шла в желательном для путников направлении. Желателен подробный анализ проекта. <**Желательно, нареч. и в функц. сказ. (с инф. или союзом чтобы).** Нужно; целесообразно; хотелось бы. Ж., чтобы всё уладилось. Ж. было бы выслушать мнение автора. Для наблюдения ж. выбрать открытую площадку.

Здесь указаны два возможных варианта (с инф. или союзом чтобы).

(1) Пример Грамоты.ру: *Желательно, **чтобы** в предложении было не более десяти слов.*

(2) С инфинитивом надо составить самим: *В предложении желательно **использовать** не более десяти слов.*